# PowerApps List Rows Present in a table action cannot see excel files

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform

I have access to a SharePoint site folder that has Excel files (both CSV and XSLX). I can see the files and can open them

I am creating a PowerApps flow to read all the rows in the file and import them to a Dataverse table.

So, in the flow I added the Excel Business action: List Rows Present in a table. The connector uses my credentials.

When I configure the action, I am able to select the SharePoint location and the Document Library. I can drill down into the library and get to the files' folder. However, the folder does not show any of the files; the folder says No Items.

Team site members and visitors have edit access.

What am I not setting correctly?
thanks

Comment: Are those file published properly in case you have content approval enabled on this library? Are you able to see the files in library using the same account you are using to create a flow?

Comment: I can see the files and even edit them with the same user.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect excel directly in SharePoint folder. It has to be in OneDrive.
If you want a live connection with the data put the file in your personal or business OneDrive.

If don't want a live connection, you can also import the file into Powerapps directly. But that means anytime you make changes to the file, you have to import it again

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't understand.... Why is there a SharePoint online activity if the file cannot connect directly? is there a way to automatically (i.e. triggered) import the file into PowerApps?

Comment: As far as I know, unfortunately, there is currently no such a way. To address your concern about the situation, we’d suggest you go to feedback on this issue, this is the best platform to let us hear from you and make our products and services better for you and others. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback

Comment: we moved the file to OneDrive for Business, but now i am getting an error when trying to connect: Create and authorize OAuth connection failed. OAuth2CertificateOneDriveForBusiness authorization flow failed for service 'OneDrive For Business Certificate'. Error deserializing GraphDriveResponseEntity. Exception=System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) at ConsentServer.Core.Services.Login.OneDriveForBusinessLoginStrategy.<GetResourceMetadataAsync>d__7.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same issue (or at least it seems like it) and found your post in search of an answer. It appears I have stumbled upon a solution on my own, at least one that worked for me.

The big reveal: the Excel file needs to start with a number. Why? I have zero idea. It makes no sense; it has to be a bug. But if I add a 0 to the beginning of the file, then it shows up in the list rows function.

I hope it works for you! Let me know if you find anything else that works.